# 3.7V battery charger analyse

Tags: battery-charging

I have extract this schematic from youtube (only charger parts) and create this on falstad because I want to create 3.7V battery charger. The original charger use **1N4007 diode** with **BC547 transistor**. I have only **1N4001 diode** and **2N3904 transistor**, can I use this in place? Is this circuit good or bad? I read my specs for my battery and I read 4.2 V for charge and 2.75 V for discharge, 3.7 V 70 mAh, but, my first TP point is 5 V. But probably, the battery act as resistor and then voltage down. I learn about to simulate lipo for confirm that. For any advice, thank you, sorry for my english.

[image]

Comment: There is no CC, CV , Vref or 10%CC disconnect , so it is not a good Li-ion charger design.

Comment: 1) I consider "falstad" for **educational purposes only**, it isn't really intended to design practical circuits. Especially not chargers for Lithium based cells. 2) Simulating this circuit is OK but no more than that. If you really need a working and safe Li-Ion cell charger, **this is not it**. Li-Ion based cells need to be charged quite carefully, you will need some chip for this, the TP4056 is a common type. On ebay you can buy ready made modules with this chip. These can charge a cell from a 5V supply. 3) your circuit is just too simple to be a proper Li-Ion charger.

Comment: @Bimpelrekkie , first thank's you , Yes I am aware that falstad is not the best way, but chips (ie: TP4056) are composed of transistors and other passive or active components if I'm not mistaken falstad simulates very well but on a much larger scale big visible to the eye. A capacitor stores energy so a battery can be represented by a capacitor that discharges very very slowly i think.

Comment: @Bimpelrekkie , With the values of each component I am convinced that simulation is possible in falstad but there is a lot to know and calculate. How to make a charger without a TP4056 on hand? An idea: use a 5V regulator to have a stable current, plus a voltage divider bridge to reduce the voltage to 4.2V and amperage (0.07A for my case?). But I am a beginner and this is only the result of my reflection on my level for the moment.

Comment: No, you can not use a voltage divider to create a safe charger for lithium batteries. You must be able to limit the charging voltage quite precisely, even as the charging current varies a lot.

Comment: *falstad simulates very well* Sure, for educational purposes it does. It cannot simulate an IC. You don't have the schematic of the TP4056. Maybe the TP4056 can be simulated in LTSpice. You keep insisting to "design" a Li-Ion charger. There are several reasons why you should not do that: 1) it is too complicated for a beginner 2) Falstad isn't suitable for this. But sure, go ahead and ignore the advice of basically everyone else here. We're just trying to help you hitting a brick wall at some point and being disappointed in electronics and giving up like so many have done already.

Comment: I design Analog ICs for a living, ICs that are as complex but often far more complex than the TP4056. If I would suggest to my fellow IC designers to design and simulate it with falstad because *falstad simulates very well* they'd laugh in my face and they would not take me seriously anymore. My 20 years career would go down the drain. Sure play with Falstad but keep it simple, use it for learning, that's what it is made for. Not for designing and simulating anything like an IC.

Comment: @ElliotAlderson, thank's yes i read about charging...

Comment: @Bimpelrekkie, yes i understand your opinion. Sorry I'm a novice, and this my opinion at a moment in time. Please be indulgent I 'try' to learn alone.I do not question in any way your skills or your knowledge it's not what I'm trying to do, what I'm trying to do is know how the charging of a battery works and why not even at the physical level with time.

Comment: Although Falstad has models for the 555 , and small scale logic , it uses an ideal voltage source output with a user-defined slew rate. So if it matters an output ESR must be added.  Each passive and active part needs a small ESR added to the schematic to simulate a simple design .my original comment defines the functions which need to be added to your design to work . But this discrete way is too tedious compared to Spice types or better simulators.

Comment: @TonyStewartolderthandirt I think I understand why it's complicated. thank you all

Comment: There's no need to be sorry for being a beginner, we were all beginners at some point. I know you're not questioning my opinions, I just want to steer you in the right direction to increase your chance of success. Electronics is fun but there are so many options, ways to learn today that it's easy to get lost and lose interest. And that would be a pity.

Comment: @Bimpelrekkie, yes and i thank you for that. Your comments make me aware.

Comment: This is how its done upto 3A, while the TP4046 alone can do 1A with thermal sensing http://radiostud.io/build-power-supply-portable-iot-device/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is this circuit good or bad?

Very bad.

1) For a "fully discharged" battery (2.75 V), it will only produce 22 mA of charge current. 5V -2.75 = 2.25 volts across 100 ohms.

2) At "fully charged" (4.2 V) it will continue to supply 8 mA of current into the battery.

So it will provide a VERY slow recharge, and will then do a sort of "trickle charge" after a very long time, which is not how you should charge Li batteries.

3) At no time will the "Full" and "Charging" LEDs change their brightness, since they are driven by the 5 volt supply, and that will not change with the current levels mentioned above.

4) The "Full" LED will never be on very brightly. Assuming that the "Full" LED is blue, it will have a turn-on voltage of about 3.5 volts. Then the 10k resistor ensures that the LED current will never get to more than about 0.08 mA ((5 - 3,5 - 0.7)/10000). This is hardly bright.

5) At the same time, this will produce 0.08 volts across the 1k resistor and the NPN base, which will not turn on the transistor. So the "Charging" LED will always be full on. Assuming a red LED with a 2 volt Vf, this will produce about 15 mA in the LED.

6) If you were to connect the 10k to the battery itself, that would at least make some sort of conceptual sense, but it still wouldn't work. The combination of 10k and diode drops would ensure that the LEDs would never change.

EDIT - Having watched part of the Youtube (I don't speak the language used - Hindi?) It's clear that the 5 volt supply must be current limited to the desired charge current. Also, the 10k shown in the OP is incorrect - it's a 10k variable resistor which is set for some lower resistance than 10k. Presumably the procedure for setting the pot is discussed in the video, but I am unable to evaluate it. Under these circumstances, the circuit might work, sort of.

An important point to consider is that the circuit has no automatic shutoff. The user must monitor the circuit, and when the "Full" LED turns off the user must disconnect the battery. The claims in the Youtube that the circuit is safe are only true if this occurs. Otherwise, the guy who made the video is simply displaying his incompetence.

END EDIT

2ND EDIT

I forgot to mention that the Youtube circuit has no resistors in series with the battery. I have no idea where those 50 ohm resistors came from, and I have no idea why anyone would want to put them there. At the very least, they will prevent drawing more than a few mA from the battery to the load. If the "Blink LED" is the only load, it will work well enough, but at the same time is unnecessary given the 1k limiting resistor.

So, yeah, this is a bad circuit.

END 2ND EDIT

Comment: Thank's for your reply, i have put 5V on input but in tutorial it's not specified. Does this change anything about the reliability of this scheme? I guess no, but ...

Comment: What I do not understand also is why this is on [youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uwGG6SI6lq8)  and that a lot of people try this circuit, that the author of the video answers and says that it is functional, there is still a risk of explosion of the battery, it's dangerous no?

Comment: From the tutorial comments, I confirm 5V for input. I read from user : 'Is it safe to charge lithium battery using this charger?' And the author : 'Yes my dear friend....' . But you bring me the elements that make me think the opposite but that I can not confirm by my lack of knowledge so I do not know what to deduce.

Comment: Thank you very much for your time and your answer. About your first edit: Indeed I do not know the language of the author either .Hindi I think too. For variable resistance 10K, yes actually I knew it but I wanted to try like this to start. I also asked the question for the charging current and you just confirmed what I learned by reading on the internet.

Comment: For the monitoring of the battery until the full charge of it I suspected but nothing confirmed it to me since I am currently learning the charging process of lipo batteries.
About your second edit: 50 ohm resistors are simply tests of a representation / simulation of a lipo battery. This is to ignore. All schemtic right part are tests.

Comment: From what I read, I have to adjust the voltage to 4.2V constantly (charge value found in the data sheet of my battery) with a constant current of 0.07A for charging a 3.7V lipo battery, 70mAh. And if I understand correctly my battery should not discharge below 2.75V (discharge value in the datasheet of my battery). Can you confirm if I'm right for the theory ? Thank you.

Comment: @f14284 - Without seeing the data sheet,  I cannot answer your question. And 2.5 to 2.75 (depends on manufacturer) are the usual discharge cutoff points. If you go lower than this the lifetime of the battery will be reduced, but you probably won't immediately kill it. Finally, you should not produce a schematic which is not representative of the circuit you are asking about. By including the 50 ohm resistors "to ignore" without mentioning the fact wastes the time of people who are helping you for free.

Comment: Ok thank you,first here, specs. of my lipo (I can not find the real data sheet but information is provided here): [link](http://www.pchub.com/uph/laptop/1124-81352-18740/UPH-Battery-Recharge-Pack-with-Wire.html). secondly, in my description, I specify: "I am learning to simulate lipo ..." and the parts of the diagram are clearly specified on the box with the textual notation. So, at the level of time lost for those who make the decision to help me (yes for free but I do not force them), I wanted to tell them, read before answering (without offense).

Comment: But I agree that it was not necessary for less confusion.